# How to customize dialog window icon using WIX?

Tags: dialog, wix, icons, customization, wix3.5

Is it possible to change standard icon (small icon, which is displayed on the left from title of setup dialog window)?
There was used WIX 3.5 for setup's dialogs creation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, Windows Installer doesn't support changing the window icon.

Comment: Is this still the same or there is a way to customize this? I am asking this because I have seen installers where this icon is different. I mean, the computer icon at the top left in every dialog, in the status bar during installation.