# How to replace computer + disk icon using during installs in WiX?

Tags: wix

Is it possible to replace the ancient looking computer + disk image that msiexec displays during install using WiX 3.5?  If so how?

[image]

I'm not currently using using WixUI.  I am open to using it, as long as I can get just a plain, zero-click installation experience.

I've tried all of the WixVariables suggested on this page: http://wix.tramontana.co.hu/tutorial/user-interface/ui-wizardry but no luck.  Thanks for any help.

Comment: p.s. This post may answer my question, but couldn't tell if it was talking about the same icon http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6680527/how-to-customize-dialog-window-icon-using-wix

Comment: It does answer your question. It's not the same icon exactly (that post is talking about the program icon which shows up in alt+tab and the left of the titlebar), but it has the same problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you can't change it.

This icon comes from `msiexec.exe`, which is the Windows Installer service.
Changing the icon in this system dialog as well as [window icon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6680527/how-to-customize-dialog-window-icon-using-wix) is not supported.